# How does ASP.NET InProc session work? Are race conditions possible with read-only session?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, session

I want to clarify some details of ASP.NET session. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3.
Let's say I have a controller marked with `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` attribute - so it uses read-only session.
Session is in `InProc` mode.
According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx), requests to this controller acquire a read lock and cannot update the session.
I want to understand **if racing conditions are still possible** between these requests (within a common session) if they try to update the session values?
These requests use the same session data structure, not separate copies of it, right?
How `InProc` session values are updated? At once or in `OnReleaseState` event at the end of request?
What happens in `OnReleaseState` handler?

**UPDATE**

I'm investigating the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'MyKey'  Key being added: 'MyKey'
at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
at System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseAdd(String name, Object value)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.set_Item(String name, Object value)
```

that happens when simply accessing a session's value: `(DateTime)context.Session["MyKey"]`.

[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2008/06/21/argumentexception-when-adding-objects-in-session-item-has-already-been-added-to-the-dictionary.aspx) describes very similar exception with ASP.NET session.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you only store immutable objects in Session, there is no risk of a race condition.  Multiple read locks can be held simultaneously, but a read lock can not be acquired while a write lock is held, and a write lock can not be acquired while a read lock is held.

You can run into trouble if you store mutable, non-thread-safe objects in Session, and then mark an Action as using readonly Session.

In this situation, you will be prevented (*) from adding/replacing objects in Session.

(*) actually you can add/replace them, but they won't persist beyond the end of the request.

But you will not be prevented from attempting to mutate the state of an object in Session.

If your app has mutable objects in Session, I suggest you steer clear of using read-only Session.

**UPDATE** in response to comments

> What if I try to set a value under a reader lock

It will only last for the duration of the request: you'll be working on a shallow copy of the InProc Session collection.

> I'm investigating System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert

What does the stack trace say?
Are you inserting in a Hashtable that is already present in Session?  In which case you can have a race condition as stated above.

Comment: What if I try to set a value under a reader lock? Or in this case the request will automatically acquire a writer lock?
I'm investigating System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert that happens when trying to access a value in session.

Comment: Joe, thanks a lot for the time you're taking to answer my questions. I've updated my question. There's also a very interesting post describing a similar (as it seems to me) issue.